# Mapping Python pandas DataFrame column values to other values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a `targets` column, and I assigned them to `y`:

`y = df['targets']`

```
0         APPLE
1         APPLE
2        ORANGE
3         APPLE
4         APPLE
         ...  
9995     ORANGE
9996     ORANGE
9997      APPLE
9998     ORANGE
9999     ORANGE
Name: class, Length: 10000, dtype: object
```

I need to change my categoric features to `int` and to do that I constructed a `dict`, with all of categorical features as `key` and `int` as `value`:

```py
target_mapping = {
    'APPLE': 0,
    'ORANGE': 1,
    'AVACADO': 2
}
```

How can one use the `.map` function to change the values in `y`?

The expected output should look like:

```
0         0
1         0
2         1
3         0
4         0
         ...  
9995      1
9996      1
9997      0
9998      1
9999      1
Name: class, Length: 10000, dtype: object
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself, and what are you having issues with?  Here are the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for the map function.

Comment: `y.map(target_mapping)`?

Comment: @S3DEV i'm tried some `lambda` functions but cant find the solution for now

Comment: Gotcha.  Can you please update your question with your attempts, and we’ll be happy to guide you through it.  Tip: no lambda needed, just copy what’s in the docs.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

target_mapping = {
    'APPLE': 0,
    'ORANGE': 1,
    'AVOCADO': 2
}
df = pd.DataFrame({"targets": ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "ORANGE", "AVOCADO"]})
df["targets"] = df["targets"].map(lambda x: target_mapping[x])
```

**N.B.1** I replaced the word of the post `AVACADO` to `AVOCADO` (I assumed it was a typo)

**N.B.2** The solution assumes that `target_mapping` keys are the same of all the possible values in `df["target"]`

Comment: No need for the lambda here. ```df["targets"] = df["targets"].map(target_mapping)``` works just fine.